# Missing field in Mongo/Mongoose Query Results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to publish a node app to my Raspberrypi (the closest thing I have to a dedicated server XD ) for some of my friends to test a little web-app I wrote, but for some reason one of the queries is not working correctly on the pi when it does on my ide (cloud 9).

Here is the schema:

```
var campaignSchema = new Schema({
    gameMaster: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Users"
    },
    players: [{
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
      ref: "Users"
    }],
    name: String,
    gameSystem: String,
    subSystem: String
});
```

And here is the query:

```
db.Campaign.findOne({'_id' : req.params.campaign}, 'gameMaster players')
.exec(function(err, campaign){
    console.log(campaign);
});
```

Which results in :

```
{ 
    _id: 556f09195865094845a0d522, 
    players: [] 
}
```

But doing `db.campaigns.find({})` in mongo results in:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("556f09195865094845a0d522"), 
    "gameMaster" : ObjectId("556d1daf4b9b697213468827"), 
    "gameSystem" : "Nwodv2", 
    "subSystem" : "Demon", 
    "name" : "Baltimore", 
    "players" : [ ], 
    "__v" : 0 
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something... I don't have any idea how to resolve this though, I tried the query without a limiter on the fields, but it still omitted the `gameMaster` field...

Edit: at request here is the creation of the Campaign object

```
var campaign = new db.Campaign({
        gameMaster: userid,
        gameSystem: req.body.system,
        subSystem: req.body.subsystem,
        name: req.body.name
    });
```

To be further confounding, this query works:

```
db.Campaign.findOne({'_id' : req.params.campaign}, 
    '_id name gameSystem subSystem gameMaster players') 
    .populate('gameMaster', '_id displayName')
    .populate('players', '_id displayName')
    .exec(function(err, campaign) {
      //gameMaster is valid here with the id and displayName populated...
    });
```

Comment: @JohnnyHK 
I added it to the original post.
The userid is an objectid of the logged in user.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux
Yes. I verified the User does exist that is referenced.

Comment: @JohnnyHK `module.exports.Campaign = conn.model("Campaigns", campaignSchema);` Where `conn` is a mongoose connection.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I corrected the question, I am querying `db.campaigns` not `db.Campaigns` Only the lower case version exists.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I fixed that and added a working query that uses the gameMaster field (albeit populated...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3020

If anyone else is having this issue. I found this bug report that can explain the cause of the problem, it is related to how you install the new mongoose 4 apparently.